# Generic TypeScript type for filters

Tags: mongodb, typescript, typescript-generics

I have generic repository interface:

```
type RecursivePartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?:
    T[P] extends (infer U)[] ? RecursivePartial<U>[] :
    T[P] extends object ? RecursivePartial<T[P]> :
    T[P];
};

interface Repository<T> {
  all(filters?: RecursivePartial<T>): T[] | Promise<T[]>;
  find(filters: RecursivePartial<T>): T | undefined | Promise<T | undefined>;
  create(entity: T): T | Promise<T>;
  update(entity: T, fields: RecursivePartial<T>): T | Promise<T>;
}
```

When I want to find an entity

```
repository.find({ property: value })
```

works fine. But now when I have repository which queries data from MongoDB, I need a type which both supports exact filtering as well as query like

```
repository.find({ property: { $exists: true } })
```

P.S. Maybe you know how to deal with **Promise<T> | T**

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an extra union type to the `T[P]` base case:

```
type HigherFilter = {
    $exists?: boolean,
};

type RecursivePartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?:
    T[P] extends (infer U)[] ? RecursivePartial<U>[] :
    T[P] extends object ? RecursivePartial<T[P]> :
    T[P] | HigherFilter; // <---- HERE
};
```

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEglgcwBYQE4DE4BthqgXigG8AoKcqAEggA84BnYegfgC4oAjAey6wgEMAdgBoSAXwDcJEqEhQAShADGAV1T04ANwgAFfqmBx+WADwAVAHwFiZKAG0dUOIKgBrCCC4AzKGYC6bLbkZg5+ULS4ggAm9FAAFM5eeACqAJR2YcwKymoa2noGRqbJFhlQrEG+oeE0kTFQXBwAVsrAUFmKqupauvqGxuahVhUUVTphAD6wiCgY2LioUpLSzgte-ErQimBcGsBcqCDmVqTkxlhxXvNoLOyduT0F-aaWqewhk1A6qFwAtgwQQZ+CxSchXaKXa7qO45br5PpFY5vXxQKYqaIQcEQKKor4-f70QFmXHoqKY5zYkG2JSoAS4OIQQSGUDvZHEqbfP4A46gqAqMBRfj0xnMkDvYRQK4QLAxGFdPK9QoDV7vXGcglEqliaRKLiCRhQWk7PYHMXZY1wfaHExEKBgH6QAxmwQqX4cNASskQMDsW2Cfi-CDsRioZwIKBiCNWQgABig-FiQhAUiNu0tpoAdOConFbfauI6WVAAKwxuNiVIp71pq0gLPOHN5h1oIu26h0Rj0djAVAqaCRiskVMmw71iG2r0+4hQf2B9gAcgAGoyfvOIxHUkPqyO69nc1BJ76ZwGg9P2wwmN3e-314OgA)